# Cannot connect using SQL Server JDBC driver

Tags: sql-server, ballerina

When attempting to use ballerina/jdbc with the Microsoft JDBC driver I receive:

```
error: ballerina/runtime:CallFailedException, message: call failed
at ..<stop>(jdbc_test.bal:4) caused by error at ballerina/jdbc:stop(endpoint.bal:66)
```

Has anyone been able to accomplish this?

I'm using:

- Ballerina 0.981.1
- Microsoft JDBC Driver 7.0 for SQL Server (with mssql-jdbc-7.0.0.jre10.jar placed into C:\Program Files\Ballerina\ballerina-0.981.1\bre\lib)
- VS Code 1.27.1

Here's a repro:

```
import ballerina/jdbc;

endpoint jdbc:Client testDB {
    url: "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;integratedSecurity=true;",
    poolOptions: { maximumPoolSize: 5 }
};

function main(string... args) {
}
```

I've tried connecting to my local sql server as well as an Azure SQL instance. I've also tried connecting with SQL Server authentication using both

```
endpoint jdbc:Client testDB {
    url: "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;user=[user];password=[pass];",
    poolOptions: { maximumPoolSize: 5 }
};
```

and

```
endpoint jdbc:Client testDB {
    url: "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;",
    username: "[user]",
    password: "[pass]",
    poolOptions: { maximumPoolSize: 5 }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried SQL authentication? That unhelpful and mysterious "call failed" sounds like it could be the result of the integrated authentication failing. If it is, you have something more specific to investigate.

Comment: Same thing, unfortunately. I've edited my original post.

Comment: Then you need to get a refund from the people who wrote this code, or demand a tribute in chocolate if no money exchanged hands, because that message is criminally unhelpful. A more extensive stack trace would be the least thing I'd expect. You could try writing the "boring" alternative in plain old Java first, to verify that the JDBC driver works on the most basic level. (If that too gives "call failed", then the chocolate tribute must be extracted elsewhere, but at least you know Ballerina isn't at fault anywhere.)

Comment: Can you connect from your machine using ODBC or a UDL file?

Comment: Yes. UDLs and DSNs over ODBC work fine.

Comment: The generic exception was due to the following issue
https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/10032

This is now fixed in master branch.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I had to switch from the mssql-jdbc-7.0.0.jre10.jar driver to mssql-jdbc-7.0.0.jre8.jar.